# Operators not referencing the same global variable

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am defining a global variable `timestamp` with multiple operators referencing this variable. It seems that this variable is redefined when each operator is run? Below is a minimal reproducible example. I expected that both `test` and `test2` would print the same timestamp, but they are printing different timestamps (seconds apart) in Airflow.

```
import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

start_date = datetime.datetime(
    year=2022,
    month=3,
    day=30,
    hour=18,
    minute=0,
)

timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")

def test():
    print(timestamp)

def test2():
    print(timestamp)

with DAG(
    'airflow_test',
    description='airflow test',
    max_active_runs=1,
    start_date=start_date,
    ) as dag:
        
        test = PythonOperator(
            task_id='test',
            python_callable=test,
            dag=dag
        )
        
        test2 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='test2',
            python_callable=test2,
            dag=dag
        )
        
        test >> test2
```

What is actually happening internally when this script is run by Airflow that causes this to occur?

Comment: I don't know the internals of airflow, but I bet it is creating a new python process per operator

Answer (score 0):

i prefer use airflow default builtin like:

```
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
```

example:

```
    project_cfg = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'email': ['your-email@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(hours=1),
     }
```

for your question i prefer use [xcom](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html) to refrence your global variable

another way is make a function and call it for each task or make local variable

or try this one:

```
with DAG(dag_id="test",
         start_date=days_ago(3),
         schedule_interval="@daily",
         catchup=False) as dag:
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    @task
    def test1():
        return timestamp
    
    @task
    def test2():
        return timestamp

    
    test2(test1())
```

i hope it'll help full